# How to save stripe webhook response on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using flutter as a client-side and using the [firebase extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments) to get the checkout URL for payment purposes.

This is working fine but I want to save the webhook response data on my MySQL db. The stripe webhook sends data on each event and I want to store each event response on my DB by which I will filter the data from there.

I am using node js as the backend but I don't have much knowledge of nodejs.
I followed the [stripe nodejs documentation](https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks/create) from which I am triggering the events
and this is the documentation code -

```
  // server.js
//
// Use this sample code to handle webhook events in your integration.
//
// 1) Paste this code into a new file (server.js)
//
// 2) Install dependencies
//   npm install stripe
//   npm install express
//
// 3) Run the server on http://localhost:4242
//   node server.js

const stripe = require('stripe');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
const endpointSecret = "whsec_a86c898114804f99965ae4a14a7a93731a4c0bdffa506fa3d24d73ac89dd56f3";

app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'checkout.session.async_payment_failed':
      const session = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event checkout.session.async_payment_failed
      break;
    case 'checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded':
      const session = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.created':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.created
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.processing':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.processing
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.send();
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

now, how can I connect MySQL on each switch case and save the data on my mysql db.

**(note - I dont have pior knowledge of nodejs and mysql I have just read the documentation and following everything)**